Cant' start Selenium Web Scraper on Ubuntu VM
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

I get this error.

Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error starting process: /home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser/bin/Debug/net8.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --language-binding csharp --output json
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser/bin/Debug/net8.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' with working directory '/home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser'. Permission denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.BinaryPaths(String arguments)
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.BinaryPaths()
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.GetDriverPath()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver.GenerateDriverServiceCommandExecutor(DriverService service, DriverOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at AvitoParser.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser/Program.cs:line 51

I already installed chromedriver and google-chrome stable version. But this app still doesn't start.

Whatever user is trying to execute /home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser/bin/Debug/net8.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium/manager doesn't have the permission to do so. Check the permissions with ls -la and make sure the user executing it has the correct permissions.

Can't do a comment yet, so...
...An error occurred trying to start process '/home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser/bin/Debug/net8.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' with working directory '/home/lartsevalex/NewAvitoParser'. Permission denied

Permission denied
Giving permissions to the user that runs this program might resolve this.

drwxrwxr-x 2 lartsevalex lartsevalex    4096 Oct 15 13:03 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 lartsevalex lartsevalex    4096 Oct 15 13:03 ..
-rw-rw-r-x 1 lartsevalex lartsevalex 5499200 Oct 15 13:03 selenium-manager
i think is not work for me. Or i dont understand something, its quite possible
